# Gutenberg: How to enqueue scripts conditionally in render_callback by checking for an attribute?

Tags: block-editor

This code works perfecly fine in Twenty-Twenty-Two but not in Twenty-Twenty or other themes:

```
  add_action( 'init', 'register_simpletoc_block' );

  function render_callback_simpletoc( $attributes ){ 
   if ( $attributes['accordion'] === true ) {
      add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'simpletoc_accordion_enqueue' );
   }
```

I need to enqueue scripts for the frontend for a specific feature only. What is the reason that this works in the most recent theme but not others? I did not find any process to do this in JavaScript, and I need a server-side-renderer block anyway. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The action `wp_enqueue_scripts` is called in `wp_head` which happens before your block is rendered.
If you need to enqueue scripts for your block, you can directly call [`wp_register_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/). The function 5th argument let you place the script in the footer. It should be included when `wp_footer` hook is triggered.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to replace the function. But why does it work in twenty-twenty-two?

Comment: Maybe you have something that evaluate your block before the head is printed? Have you other active plugins ?

Comment: No. The only change is the theme in a new local wp installation.

Comment: I will need to look deeper into this on the weekend

Comment: This does not work, either: 

    function render_callback_simpletoc( $attributes )
    {
 
       wp_register_script( 'simpletoc-accordion-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/src/accordion.js', '', '5.0.41', true );
        wp_register_style( 'simpletoc-accordion-css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/src/accordion.css' , '', '5.0.41', true );

Comment: wp_register_script does not enqueue the script. And wp_enqueue_scripts does have the footer option as well. Still does not work in the callback of the gutenberg block... exept I use twenty-twenty-two

Comment: Can you call `wp_enqueue_script('simpletoc-accordion-js'); wp_enqueue_style('simpletoc-accordion-css');` right after you register them?

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault all along. I used the wrong parameters in the  wp_enqueue_script and wp_enqueue_style because I assumed they both use the same parameter structure. It was the last parameter, which is either "footer" or "media". And I set "media" to true, which results in the problem.